# ImageButton not opening sliding menu Android

Tags: android, menu, logcat, imagebutton

So what im trying to do is use an ImageButton with and onClick to open the android side menu but i keep getting an error.

**home.xml** (where the ImageButton is located with the onClick)

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgViewRefresh4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:onClick="click1"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:src="@drawable/slide4" />
```

**MainActivity.java** (where the onClick is called)

```
public void click1(){
     mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

**Logcat error**

```
12-13 21:38:01.276 3949-3949/com.projects.quickyAB E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL     EXCEPTION: main
12-13 21:38:01.276 3949-3949/com.projects.quickyAB E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method click1(View) in the activity class com.projects.quickyAB.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'imgViewRefresh4'
12-13 21:38:01.276 3949-3949/com.projects.quickyAB E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3825)
12-13 21:38:01.276 3949-3949/com.projects.quickyAB E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
12-13 21:38:01.276 3949-3949/com.projects.quickyAB E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18796)
12-13 21:38:01.276 3949-3949/com.projects.quickyAB E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-13 21:38:01.276 3949-3949/com.projects.quickyAB E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-13 21:38:01.276 3949-3949/com.projects.quickyAB E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 21:38:01.276 3949-3949/com.projects.quickyAB E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your method like this to handle the click

```
public void click1(View v){
     mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```